# My ISP/Network/Government has blocked access to the TorProject website. How can I download Tor?

Tags: support, mirrors, censorship

I'm trying to download Tor but my ISP/Network administrator/Government has blocked access to the [TorProject website](https://torproject.org). How do I download Tor?

Comment: Should we be trying to reproduce the Tor FAQ here? https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#GetTor

Comment: Soon to be on the blocklist of your ISP: tor.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is answered on the FAQ page. I dont think we need to replicate the FAQ here. Voting to close.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about information present in the [TOR FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq).

Comment: @AsheeshR How is it off-topic?! That's a very common question among censored-users even though it's been always been there on Tor FAQ. Simply because they can't access Tor website for the reason I mentioned in Q. it's blocked! ps: it's Tor not TOR :)

Comment: @RogerDingledine Yes, I think we should reproduce the essential ones. Censored users will never get a chance to see Tor website, while SE is not necessarily blocked and usually gets a good rank in Google.

Comment: Blocking can either be URL based in which case torproject will be blocked but any of the mirrors wont. Any search engine like Google (when signed in) that encrypts traffic is more than enough. If its a keyword block, then Tor.SE wont be opening as well. I dont see how duplicating information thats [pretty easily available](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hod+do+i+install+tor+when+torprojectis+blocked) makes sense.

Comment: Different countries use different filtering methods. Lets say you're right about URL method. How are censored-users suppose to get the mirror list? Did you really get any useful information with that search? anything other than official website? coz I didn't.

Comment: If people don't have access to known Tor sites, then logically we will need to reproduce common FAQ information, or refer to floating mirror of the FAQ

Comment: @RogerDingledine Actually this might be an option and it's actually makes sense as Stack Exchange tries to create exactly that. That's also why you can answer your own questions directly.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You've a couple of options:

- If [Github](https://github.com) isn't blocked in your network, then you can go to the official Github website for downloading the Tor Browser which is: `https://TheTorProject.github.io/gettor` (`gettor` is case sensitive), or you can directly go the official repository for downloading the Tor Browser on Github: `https://github.com/TheTorProject/GetTorBrowser`.
- Send an email to `gettor@torproject.org` and a bot will try to send you the download links.
- Send a DM to [@get_tor](https://twitter.com/get_tor) on Twitter.
- Send a message to `gettor@torproject.org` from your favorite XMPP client.
- [Search for mirrors](https://startpage.com/do/search?q=tor%20mirror) on Internet or check the [Google cached version](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:lL3KOtiH620J:www.torproject.org/getinvolved/mirrors.html.en%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) of [Tor mirrors](https://www.torproject.org/getinvolved/mirrors.html.en) page and check if any of those links work for you.
- Contact a human via `help@rt.torproject.org`, explain your problem and ask for a mirror. Currently we're able to respond to requests in English, Farsi, Arabic, Chinese, Spanish and French.
- Get it from a friend. Tor Browser Bundle (aka TBB) is small enough to fit in a USB stick.

  *It is **very important** to [verify the signature](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) of any package you download, especially when you get it from somewhere other than Tor official HTTPS website. Even if you get it from a trusted friend.*

Comment: Your answer raises an interesting conundrum: if I can't access torproject.org, how do I verify the signatures?

Comment: @TomMedley You don't need access to torproject.org to verify the signatures. I'll describe how to do that in another Q&A.

Comment: @TomMedley You can get the signatures from Github: [https://TheTorProject.github.io/gettor](https://TheTorProject.github.io/gettor) or [https://github.com/TheTorProject/GetTorBrowser](https://github.com/TheTorProject/GetTorBrowser)

Answer (score 3):

You can download Tor from several mirror sites. One is http://tor.dev-random.de and the list of current mirrors is https://tor.dev-random.de/getinvolved/mirrors.html.en

Be aware that it is important to *always* [verify the GnuPG signature](https://tor.dev-random.de/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) of *every* file you download.

Comment: The mirrors that you have given to download Tor do not work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

There are alot of places where sources of Tor may be found, e.g. [github](https://github.com/nextgens/Tor).

You must remember that Tor is not a panacea and moreover, you must know how to use other software. There are great amount of projects which embed Tor in-self, e.g. [yet another torbrowser](http://torbrowser.sourceforge.net/), [Tails LiveCD](https://tails.boum.org/)

You can achieve torproject.org via free socks5 proxy or free vpn, e.g. [vpngate.net](http://www.vpngate.net/en/)

In many distributives of Linux you can get binary package of Tor and often sources too.

Ubuntu / Debian-based:

```
# apt-get install -y tor
```

Fedora / OpenSUSE / CentOS:

```
# yum install tor
```

Gentoo:

```
# emerge tor
```

Additionally, you can meet Tor users in [Internet Relay Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat): `irc.oftc.net:6667` **#tor**

*We will sharing with you the sources of Tor by any accessible for you hosting.*